# Unable to retrieve values from firebase

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart

I am trying to store the names from firestore in a list of string but after the termination of this method when i try to print the list it shows empty!

```
 int i = 0;
  void getDriverList() async {
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("Users")
        .get()
        .then((querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.docs.forEach((result) {
        names[i++] = result.get("name");
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  initState() {
    getDriverList();
    print(names);
    super.initState();
    // Add listeners to this class
  }
```

Comment: getDriverList(); is an async method , it will always print an empty array in your code, try to move print(names) under getDriverList method at the end

Answer (score 0):

Use querySnapshot.docs!.data.forEach...

You will get data. If not get then use print the data and find the problem why data is not coming.